# Accessing files from disk in server root

Tags: jsp, tomcat, root

I need to access some files from my jsp pages.So I kept them inside my server Root.But the no of files are likely to increase.So is there a way by which I can access those files from web server root and store them in anywhere in disk ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a symbolic link.... create a directory in your web root and

```
  ln -s directory /path/to/files
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the absolute path of the file. Read it using `FileInputStream`, write to output stream on JSP.

```
        String file = "/home/mystorage/media/file.dat";
        FileInputStream fileinputstream = new FileInputStream(file);
        int numberBytes = fileinputstream.available();
        byte bytearray[] = new byte[numberBytes];

        fileinputstream.read(bytearray);

        for(int i = 0; i < numberBytes; i++){
            out.println(bytearray[i]);
        }

        fileinputstream.close();
```

refer [Java2s Reading Binary Data](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JSP/ReadingBinaryData.htm)